# MCQ: The maximum number of linearly independent solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

The maximum number of linearly independent solution of $\dfrac{d^4y}{dx^4}=0$ with $y(0)=1$ is

A. 4

B. 3

C. 2

D. 1

My try:

By solving the DE with the condition we get

$$y=c_1x^3+c_2x^2+c_3x+1$$ where $c_i's$ are arbitrary constants.

Now $x^3,x^2,x,1$ are 4 linearly independent solutions of the given DE. Hence Ans is $A. 4$

Am I right?

Comment: Of the 4 solutions you mention, only one of them has the property that y(0)=1. You need to offset all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The 4 solutions

$$x^3+1 , x^2+1 , x+1 , 1$$

are pairwise linear independent, so the answer 4 is right.

Comment: Why is $1+x^2+x^3$ or $1+x+x^2+x^3$ not included in the list?

Comment: @Navi you can take such a solution but the thing is that OP asked for maximum number of such solutions,so this one with other 3 solutions will form a distinct set of such 4 linearly independent solutions.